# What's wrong with my SMPS circuit?

Tags: power-supply, switch-mode-power-supply, current-limiting, troubleshooting

I've proto-typed a switch mode power supply with variable voltage and current control using a MAX1763 IC. I've powered it on and for the most part it works great, I can control the voltage using the pot, but the current control pot doesn't work in the slightest when testing it. I'm not sure what the issue is, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Testing:
Applied a load and attempted to change the current while the circuit is; the current draw does not change. (Vin = 2.5v, Vout = 3.3v, load is 10ohm resistor)
I've also noticed a considerable voltage drop when load is applied.

[MAX1763 datasheet](https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX1763.pdf)

[image]

Comment: What are you expecting to happen?  Iset limits the peak inductor current.  Therefore if your load wants to draw more than the converter can supply at that peak inductor current, the output voltage will drop.  If not, then the output voltage and current draw (for a constant load) will stay the same.

Comment: What JohnD says and also: the ISET works on the inductor peak current, this current becomes **lower** (for a given output load) when the input voltage become **higher**. So your current limiting setting depends on the input voltage !